# Passing .Net Stream into IronRuby?

Tags: .net, yaml, ironruby

I am using IronRuby to parse Yaml files and then use the parsed document in C#.  This is working fine for creating an engine (`Ruby.CreateEngine()`), and executing the `YAML::load(File.open('myFile.yaml'))`.

But, this works well because I can hard-code a string for the file name when I execute a few lines of ruby code.

Now, I want to understand how to pass a stream from .Net in to have the Yaml parser load it.  How do I do this with the scripting engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable with a ScriptScope and then use it from the Ruby code.
For example:

```
ScriptEngine eng = Ruby.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = eng.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("my_stream",stream);
eng.Execute("self.my_stream.read() # or whatever...", scope);
```

Comment: But create a StreamReader and pass the StreamReader in instead of the stream. Then you can do this:
my_yaml = YAML.load(self.my_stream_reader.ReadToEnd)